# Typesetting multiple TeX files

Tags: bibliographies, input

**Q1.**  Is there an existing template with the following features:

(1) Multiple files, which I can typeset individually (as and when necessary).

(2) A single **.bib** file from which I can cite in different chapters, with links to the appendix and weblink.

Also, this is a very basic question, please let me know how to typeset the master and individual tex files as well.

**Q2.** Perhaps another silly question: can I say compile instead of typeset?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've edited your post a bit, mainly by removing the thanks line and salutation (as omitting these items is the style of this group).

Comment: I would recommend the `standalone` package, and personally don't see anything wrong with _compile_ vs _typeset_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer Q1, imagine you have `master.tex`, `indiv1.tex` and `indiv2.tex`. The challenge is to typeset `master.tex`, which includes `indiv1.tex` and `indiv2.tex` (with a bibliography) and to typeset `indiv1.tex` and `indiv2.tex` separately, also with a bibliography. The bibliography file is named "biblio.bib".

To solve the problem, create a single file named `preamble.tex` that each of `master.tex`, `indiv1.tex`, and `indiv2.tex` will include. In `preamble` put the following, which configures your bibliography and creates a command to conditionally include it:

```
%% Using biblatex to define the bibliograph.
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

% Used by included files to know they
% are NOT standalone
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{standaloneFlag}
\setboolean{standaloneFlag}{true}

%% Command to conditionally typeset a bibliography.
\newcommand{\standaloneBib}{%%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{standaloneFlag}}%%
             {\printbibliography}{}}
```

Change `indiv1.tex` and `indiv2.tex` to start with the following header and end with the `\standaloneBib` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{standalone}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
...
\standaloneBib
\end{document}
```

However, in `master.tex`, you set the `standaloneFlag` value to false, `\input` the individual files, and always print the bibliography:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{standalone}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
\setboolean{standaloneFlag}{false}
...
\input{indiv1}
\input{indiv2}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now you can run `pdflatex` on `indiv1` or `indiv2` and only that chapter will be typeset, with a bibliography. If you run `pdflatex` on `master`, it will typeset all chapters, including the bibliography.

Comment: Thanks a lot your help. I added "amscd, amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amstext, hyperref, graphicx" to your template 

I need some help with bibliographies. I have references of the following types (fr older files)

    \bibitem[Prescott, E. (1998)]
    {Prescott98}
    Prescott, E. 1998.
    \href{http://www.minneapolisfed.org/publications_papers/pub_display.cfm?id=761}
    {\emph{Business Cycle Research: Methods and Problems.}} 
    FRB Minneapolis Working Paper 590.
    \end{thebibliography}

How can I incorporate this kind of references with links in Justin's template?

Comment: The simplest thing to do is turn those items into BiBTeX entries and put them in `biblio.bib`. Please mark my response as an answer!