# Using a custom bst file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I made a custom Master Bibliographic Style File (, `merlin.bs`) [(, with all the source files from CTAN)](http://www.mediafire.com/?kg29789pv1ddpjl) using `makebst.tex`. But I don't know how to use it with [these template files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42376/fine-tuning-bibliography).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: For your second question see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need the command `\bibliographystyle{merlin}` in your file (preferably the same one in which `\printbibliography` occurs), and the `.bst` file needs to be in a place where latex can find it.

(i think that you meant `merlin.bst`, not just `merlin.bs`.)

Comment: Thanks barbara. I tired using `\bibliographystyle{merlin}` before/after `\printbibliography`. I get an error "Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid". Do I need put other merlin files in the folder? I'm not sure if I complied the `merlin.bst` file correctly. If it's too complicated/time consuming, could anyone please show me an example using any of bibliogrpahy style mentioned [here](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.pdf). Thanks.

Comment: @bakul Don't use the `biblatex` package, because that is an entirely different way to handle bibliographies, see the documentation of that package. Use `\bibliographystyle{merlin} \bibliography{myrefs}`, where myrefs is your `.bib` file.