# Can SyncTeX work across included files?

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I am using the `memoir` class in Texmaker.

As far as I understand adding

```
--synctex=1
```

to the LaTeX and PDFLaTeX command will make the output document open up at the cursor position of the code. So if I left my cursor at the start of a particular piece of text on a random page the pdf will open up at that page.

It also enables the "click to jump to line".

Since I am typing a large document I an using `\include` to include all my chapters. This means when I compile I have to compile a master document. This means the cursor is now wherever I left it in the master document.

This is a huge pain since the pdf output is sometimes nowhere near the most recently edited part that I want to view. If I am working in Chapter 5 I can go leave the cursor after

```
\include{chapterfive}
```

but then the output is always on the last page of the chapter and I still need to scroll to the relevant part.

As you can imagine this becomes very tiresome very quickly. So I need help configuring Texmaker so that the PDF output opens up at the last place that I edited.

EDIT: I found a workaround. I followed this answer: [Typesetting multiple TeX files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41635/typesetting-multiple-tex-files)

to be able to compile each chapter individually. And it worked 100%.

Comment: Not massively familiar with Texmaker: am I correct in understanding that you can't simply press/choose 'typeset' (or similar) from e.g. `chapterfive.tex`?

Comment: Does it not work if you put the cursor at the edited portion of of the included file? I'm not too familiar with Texmaker, but this has always worked for me in TeXnicCenter.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe `synctex` is only responsible for backwards search (the "click to jump to line"). Also, the answer to the very general question written in the title is probably "yes" because it does work seemlessly in my workflow (both forward and backward), but sadly I am not using `TeXmaker` so I cannot help you more with that.

Comment: @PaulGessler no I tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: @JosephWright I am not sure what you mean by press/choose 'typeset'. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JosephWright I understand what you mean now. See edit. And thanks for helping me onto the right path.

Comment: I've reverted the edit: the 'model' on the network is that the questions space is kept just for question. You can of course 'accept' the answer if you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the following works correctly:

- Load your main file in Texmaker
- Choose Options -> Define Current Document as 'Master Document'
- Open a subfile
- Edit subfile, *etc.*
- Press 'Quick Build'
- Main file builds but 'current' file stays visible, *etc.*
- SyncTeX linking is possible from source to PDF and the reverse